# Access to OpenLDAP via nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, openldap

I have an OpenLDAP which is installed in private network, only the server in same private subnet can communicate with my OpenLDAP server in order to authentication. How can I configure my OpenLDAP as domain name behind my nginx web proxy? I also have a public web proxy.

I tried with
`stream { server { listen     <ldap_port>; #TCP traffic will be forwarded to the specified server proxy_pass <AD/LDAP IP/Domain>:<ldap_port>; } }`

but seem not work